# How to pass variable values between successive for loops?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I have two successive for loops and i need to pass one of the variables' value to an instance inside the other for loop.

```
for(int x=0; x< sentence.length(); x++)  {

  int i;
  if (!Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(x)))
      i = x ;
      break;    
}

for (int  i  ; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(i)))
     if (!Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(i + 1)))
}
```

This is just a part of my program and my purpose is assigning the value of x (from the fírst for loop) to i variable (from the second for loop)  so that i wont start from 0 but from the value of x(before breaking the first for loop)...

Comment: i is local to your first loop, there is no way to make it locally accessible inside second for loop. Why don't you try with a global variable (outside first for loop), and update the variable's value before breaking out of the first for loop. You can then access the same value inside second for loop.

Comment: Why don't you use an `array` instead of an `int` in which you can add all the values from first loop and use that array variable in second loop !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x;
for(x = 0; x < sentence.length; x++)
   if(!Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(x)))
      break;

for(int i = x; i < //And so on and so fourth
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Java, is it?

You have to declare "i" variable out of the loop block. By the way, as a good practice if "i" is not a loop counter giving this variable a meaningful name (and x is not relevant for a loop counter).

Also you probably have a bug since the break is out of the conditionnal expression block (first loop).

```
int currentCharPosition = 0; //give a maningful name to your variable (keep i for loop counter)

for(int i=0; i< sentence.length(); i++) {

            if (!Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(x))){  
                currentCharPosition  = x ;
                break;  //put the break in the if block
            }

}

while( currentCharPosition < sentence.length()) {
            ...
            currentCharPosition++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about the Java block scope:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

declare your variable outside of the for loop like this

```
// Declare what you want to access outside here.
...
for(int x = 0; x< sentence.length(); x++)  {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sentenceLength = sentence.length();
int[] firstLoopData = new int[sentenceLength -1];
for(int x=0, index=0; x < sentenceLength; x++)  {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(x))){
        firstLoopData[index] = x;
        index++; 
        break; 
    }   
}

for(int tempInt: firstLoopData){
    //your code...
}
```